# SML How to define proper option

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

Why doesn't the following code doesn't work?

```
fun sum_list xs =
case xs of
    [] => NONE
 | x::xs' => SOME (x+sum_list xs')
```

This code works well when Instead of NONE it is zero and when I remove SOME. I know that for sum of an empty list zero is the reasonable answer. But why does the following example fails?

Update: Made it work by following Diego's Answer:

```
fun sum_list xs =
    case xs of
        [] => NONE
      | x => 
        let
            fun slist x =
                case x of
                    [] => 0
                  | x::xs' => x + slist xs'
        in 
            SOME (slist x)
        end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the function is made to return an `'a option` but in the lat expression you use it as if it returned an int:

```
x + sum_list xs'
```

You have to either build an internal function that works solely in lists and return numbers (not options), and then box the final result into an option, or eval the result of `sum_list` when returned to see if it contains a value or it is `NONE`. I can write both ways, but you should try before seeing the solution written.

Comment: But in the last expression, I return `SOME (x+sum_list xs')`. That should make the function to return an `'a option`, isn't it?

Comment: That's right, but the *internal* `+` implies that the *recursive call* to `sum_list` returned a number to be summed to `x`, but it returns always an option, not a number.

Comment: Thanks, made it work now. I have updated the question with my solution. Just point out if it has any error. :)